# Inheritance gadget for type member in standard?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, type-members

When programming with C++ templates, I often find it useful to define a type alias member called `type`. I've defined a kind of "identity" template:

```
template <typename T>
struct id { using type = T; };
```

I quite like that I can then often avoid putting anything between the braces of a class definition; inheriting from an `id` specialisation instead. A trivial primary template example might then be:

```
template <typename,typename>
struct Foo : id<void> {};
```

Does something like `id` exist in the standard library; or Boost?

Answer (score 2):

yes, sort of.

```
std::enable_if<true, T>
```

Comment: Right under my nose. A little obtuse all the same, but you have a point.